# Java: Including folder path in the file name for a File object

Tags: java, scala, file, objectoutputstream

I am trying to output an object to a file, and the code below works fine.

```
  val myFile = new File(myPath + "_" + myFileName)
  val myData = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile))
```

However, if I want to make myFileName under myPath like:

```
  val myFile = new File(myPath + "/" + myFileName)
  val myData = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile))
```

I got java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Any idea what I might have missed? Thank you!

Comment: It's possible the path of `myPath` doesn't exist.  You can also use `File(String, String)` to concatenate path elements together.  Consider using something like `new File(myPath).exists()` to check to see if the path exists and/or `File#mkdirs` to create the path - be sure to check the return result, as the path may be invalid or you don't have write permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If folder `myPath` does not exists the `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown. You have to create that folder first. You may do it manually or by `mkdir()` method from `File` class.

Answer (score 0):

This error is definitely due to missing folder referenced by "mypath" or myFileName.
JDK7 has nice abstraction for path in which you don't have to worry about path separator character (i.e /)

Use Paths
for eg 
Path p = Paths.get("c:", myPath ,myFileName)
You can extract file object from path and do whether path exists before starting any processing.